# How to validate array's key as form data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to validate array's key as form data in codeigniter.

I have used it like below but its not working.

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules("general[FirstName]", "Name", "trim|required|max_length[100]");
 $this->form_validation->set_rules("contact[Email]", "Email", "trim|required|valid_email");
 $this->form_validation->set_rules("contact[Phone]", "Phone", "trim|xss_clean|max_length[15]");
 $this->form_validation->set_rules("contact[AlternatePhone]", "AlternatePhone", "trim|xss_clean|max_length[15]");
 $this->form_validation->set_rules("contact[AddressLine1]", "AddressLine1", "trim|xss_clean|required");
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Actually I want to save multiple panel at submit and every panel has a specific array, So I want to validate array keys.

Comment: can u  show me your form

Comment: Resolved it via custom validation, I have overwrite the form library and changed the run method by copying it and customized according to requirement. If anyone want code I can provide.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('contact[0][Email]', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules("contact[1][Phone]", "Phone", "trim|xss_clean|max_length[15]");
```

This example will work if your request array is like :-

```
"contact":[{
    "Email":"test@example.com"
},
{
    "Phone":"9870231645"
}]
```

You can iterate the array and put validation dynamically for each fields instead of using hard code index.